# Передача параметра именованному шаблону в xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

Помогите, пожалуйста, исправить код.

На [странице](http://prozaik.16mb.com/question/par/index.xml) есть ошибка. Причина в том, что я неправильно передаю параметр именованной функции. Вот кусок кода

```
<pre>
                <xsl:call-template name="head" >
                <xsl:with-param name="pagetitle">
                    <xsl:value-of select="//fio/f"/>
                </xsl:with-param>
            </xsl:call-template>    
</pre>
```

Без передачи параметра ошибок нет и код работает.

[Вот](http://prozaik.16mb.com/question/par/xml_test_xml.rar) все файлы одним архивом, если так удобнее смотреть.

Answer (score 1):

Параметр вы передаёте правильно, однако выводите неправильно.

parts.xsl, строка 8: `<title>`**`<xsl:value`** `select="$pagetitle" /></title>`

Нет в xslt такого элемента. Там надо **`<xsl:value-of select="..." />`**

Comment: сделал по вашему, но проблема осталась...
http://prozaik.16mb.com/question/par4/index.xml

вот ссылка на полный архив
http://prozaik.16mb.com/question/par4/xml_test_xml.rar

Comment: я разобрался. отбой